# How to search for negated content in Datadog

Tags: datadog

I'd like to search for all the messages having certain service and NOT having certain content (message). It's straightforward to search for messages with the matching content. But how to negate them so I can filter out the messages I don't want to see (the ones polluting the context)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

given that the message of a log is
`Query parameters in page load`
and the service where the log come from is `frontend-prod`

you can use the following

```
service:frontend-prod  NOT(query)
// or
service:frontend-prod  -query
```

https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/

PS. in case you want to use a keyword that includes special characters you must have them encoded
ex.

```
service:frontend-prod  NOT(page%20load)
// or
service:frontend-prod  -page%20load
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, just one additional note - if you'd wish to match longer sentence, instead of url encoding it one can wrap it into double quotes